# Javascript not Alerting String Variable Value From Database in Code behind C#, but alerting integer variable, why?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, database, string

I am facing issue with alerting Database value fetching in code behind C# and alerting them at client side. Issue is for string value. 
E.g - Suppose any user has set their password as integer, then the code is easily alerting the value, but if the password is string then it's not alerting any thing. Even it not alerting as 'undefined', while value is there with variable.

See the below example

Code Behind C#

```
public string strPassword = string.Empty;
public string strEmailPassword = string.Empty;
var objData = UserBusiness.GetUserByID(strUserID);
if (objData != null)
{
    strPassword = objData.Password;
    strEmailPassword = objData.EmailPwd;
}
```

At JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var strPwd = <%= strPassword %> ;
    $('#<%= txtLoginPassword.ClientID%>').val(strPwd);
    var strEmailPwd = <%= strEmailPassword %> ;
    $('#<%= txtEmailPwd.ClientID%>').val(strEmailPwd);
});
```

Comment: Both these variables are passwords ?

Comment: Take a look at the generated javascript, aren't you missing quotes? `var strPwd = 123;` will work but `var strPwd = myPassword;` won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JavaScript code like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var strPwd = '<%= strPassword %>' ;
    $('#<%= txtLoginPassword.ClientID%>').val(strPwd);
    var strEmailPwd = "<%= strEmailPassword %>" ;
    $('#<%= txtEmailPwd.ClientID%>').val(strEmailPwd);
});
```

Reason: Strings must be place inside quotes `'` or `"` and integers doesn't need quotes